# How can I enable command blocks on my Minecraft realm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I have created a Minecraft realm, and want to use command blocks(since I created it, I am opped).  I got a command block using the `/give` command; however, when I tried to run a command, it told me that command blocks weren't enabled.  How can I enable them?

Comment: I don't know if I'm sure, but in the configuration page you can enable command blocks.

Comment: This question gives me a reason to use the realms free trial!

Comment: @Judge2020 That's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can enable command blocks on Realms:

1. Go to configure your realm- 
   [image: configure realm]
2. Go to world options. These options can differentiate between the three worlds. [image]
3. From here you can configure the command block allowance, among other things. [image]